# How to get the value of a dynamically generated field name in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Sample code trimmed down the the bare essentials to demonstrate question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest4() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
   wc_row wc_files%ROWTYPE;
   fieldName TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO wc_row FROM wc_files WHERE "fileNumber" = 17117;
 -- RETURN wc_row."fileTitle"; -- This works. I get the contents of the field.
    fieldName := 'fileTitle';
 -- RETURN format('wc_row.%I',fieldName); -- This returns 'wc_row."fileTitle"'
                                          -- but I need the value of it instead.
    RETURN EXECUTE format('wc_row.%I',fieldName); -- This gives a syntax error.
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I get the value of a dynamically generated field name in this situation?

Comment: The right way to using the `EXECUTE` statement in such cases: `execute format('select $1.%I',fieldName) into result using wc_row;` and then `return result;` (variable `result` should be declared)

Comment: Fantastic! I struggled with this for many hours. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a trick with the function [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html), which for a composite type returns a json object with column names as keys:

```
create or replace function mytest4() 
returns text as $$
declare
   wc_row wc_files;
   fieldname text;
begin
    select * into wc_row from wc_files where "filenumber" = 17117;
    fieldname := 'filetitle';
    return to_json(wc_row)->>fieldname;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tricks. [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) does what you need, you were on the right track already. But `RETURN EXECUTE ...` is not legal syntax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest4(OUT my_col text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   field_name text := 'fileTitle';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM wc_files WHERE "fileNumber" = 17117', field_name)
   INTO my_col;  -- data type coerced to text automatically.
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Since you only want to return a scalar value use [`EXECUTE .. INTO ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) - optionally you can assign to the `OUT` parameter directly.
  [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ..`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65549) is for returning a *set of* values.
- Use `format()` to conveniently escape identifiers and avoid SQL injection. Provide identifiers names case sensitive! `filetitle` is not the same as `fileTitle` in this context.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- Use an `OUT` parameter to simplify your code.