# Postgresql dynamic cursor (for record in EXECUTE), field access

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Suppose the block below:

```
do $$
declare
v_table_name text:='table_name';
v_column_name text:='column_name';
v_record record;
v_sql_dynamic text;
v_enum_xml xml;
v_string text;
begin
  v_sql_dynamic:=format('select %s from %s',v_column_name,v_table_name);
  FOR v_record IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic
  LOOP
   raise notice 'field with name % has a value of %',v_column_name,***?????***;
  END LOOP;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

How do I get access to the field of v_record in the way like: `v_record.v_column_name`?

Comment: `to_jsonb(v_record)->>v_column_name`

Comment: Yip, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[See Abelisto's comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745996/postgresql-dynamic-cursor-for-record-in-execute-field-access#comment72611702_42745996) While converting the value to `text` anyway, `to_json()` is good enough and slightly faster.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   v_table_name   text := 'table_name';
   v_column_name  text := 'column_name';
   v_sql_dynamic  text := format('select %s from %s', v_column_name, v_table_name);
   v_record       record;
BEGIN
   FOR v_record IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'field named % has value %.'
    , v_column_name, to_json(v_record) ->> v_column_name;
   END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [How to get the value of a dynamically generated field name in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808133/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-dynamically-generated-field-name-in-pl-pgsql/39812325#39812325)